# Does IDataReader.Dispose() close the connection?

Tags: .net, dispose, idatareader

The typical query execution pattern I inherited is like so:

```
using (IDataReader r = query.ExecuteReader())
{
  while (r.Read())
  {
    // etc.
  }
}
```

Is `query.Connection` left open after the `using` block is exited?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No; the connection will not be closed until you dispose the connection.

However, if you pass `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection`, the connection will be closed.

Comment: is it ok to put a `r.Close();` after the `while {}` instruction?

Comment: found it [Retrieving Data Using a DataReader (ADO.NET)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(VS.100).aspx) silly question though

Answer (score 6):

```
ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
```

This will close the connection when the datareader has it's `close()` method called (which occurs when the `dispose()` method is called through usage of the `using` block.

Ideally, you would use a `using` block with your `SqlConnection` object as well (or call `dispose()` manually inside a `finally` block), not just to close the connection, but also to release the resources.